# Toggling files in :Gstatus window by pressing - displays "Press ENTER or type command to continue" message

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I tried everything I found [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoiding_the_%22Hit_ENTER_to_continue%22_prompts) and [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/message.html#hit-enter) to get rid of the message to no avail.

If I set cmdheight to >1 then it works for a few toggles and then displays the dreaded message again. (I could set cmdheight to e.g 3 to prevent this but the command line looks ugly that way)

I tried to find what message makes it display the message by checking the `:file!` value:

```
".git/index" [Not edited][RO] line 10 of 10 --100%-- col 1
```

That should not be a problem, I guess.

I also checked the `:v:scrollstart` variable:

```
1 # On branch master
2 # Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
3 #
4 # Changes not staged for commit:
5 #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
6 #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
7 #
8 # modified:   zshrc
9 #
10 no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

which could be it but I'm not sure about that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is the key binding. Try:

```
:nnoremap - :<C-U>silent! execute <SNR>20_StageToggle(line('.'),line('.')+v:count1-1)<CR>
```

If that fixes it, you'll want to update fugitive.vim with the corresponding change

Beyond that, you can use debug mode

```
:debug execute <SNR>20_StageToggle(line('.'),line('.')+v:count1-1)
```

Lastly, see whether files (especially .git/index or .git/index.lock) are accessible and writable.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up submitting an issue (and the suggested fix) to the [fugitive repository](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/190).